# Nesting semantic html tags inside a div affects the use of assistive technologies?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, semantic-markup, accessibility

Can assistive technologies work properly if semantic tags are nested within a div used as a container to create the webpage layout?

I used to create the layout first with div containers using grid or flexbox, and later put the content inside, But I was wondering if this way of work affects the normal flow of assistive technologies.

Comment: Websites like this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/semantic-html explain how semantic tags work and give a bunch of examples, but any of these explains how all these interact with a fully developed website with all the required elements and CSS applied.

Comment: Questions about SEO are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ArmandoEndzelis No they are not. Programming questions with objective answers are acceptable. SEO questions don't have objective answers because search engines do not publish their SEO metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many semantic elements (e.g. `footer`, `header`, etc.) aren't that much different from a `div` CSS-wise. So, you can certainly customize them straight away without wrapping them.

I guess (mostly based on A11Y guides I've read through & [axe](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core) output) that nesting doesn't really matter. It's to say, *mostly* a `footer` and a `footer` wrapped into a `div` are equivalent.

It depends on context for sure, there are elements (e.g. `table`, `ul`) that can only have children of certain types. Nesting in those contexts could lead to invalid (and not a11y-friendly) markup.

In the wild, I've mostly seen that people consider it "clean" to maintain the "top-level" markdown (`header`, `nav`, `menu`, `main`, `section`, `article`, `footer`) unwrapped (partially, because it's quite easy to achieve, I think, since you don't normally have a lot of CSS attached to those) & wrap all the rest as needed since "down there" on lover levels, the markup tends to get way less structured anyway.
All this however, seems to be rather a matter of preference.

Comment: Basically this => "It's to say, mostly a footer and a footer wrapped into a div are equivalent." answer my question. In my personal and naive opinion is easier to wrap sections with div in order to apply the styles and work organized, but of course, my intention is to learn the correct way from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth checking out how the **[Document Object Model (DOM)](https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-constructing-the-object-model/#document-object-model-(dom))** is created to understand:

> Tokenizing: The browser converts strings of characters into distinct
> tokens—as specified by the W3C HTML5 standard for example, "`<html>`",
> "`<body>`"—and other strings within angle brackets. Each token has a
> special meaning and its own set of rules.

Here it is worth paying attention to the phrase "Each token has a special meaning and its own set of rules". Now let's check the rule for `<div>` from **[HTML5 standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)**:

> The div element has no special meaning at all.

The div element is not a semantic element, and in this, it differs from semantic elements.

If you want to style the div element, then this may also not be a winning trick for constructing the Object Model. Styles have the task of presenting content to the user. When building the **[CSS Object Model (CSSOM)](https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-constructing-the-object-model/#css-object-model-(cssom))**, styles are tightly bound by rules to HTML elements (tokens). This brings us back to the semantics of HTML elements (tokens).

So your question is related to understanding the semantics of tokens (HTML elements). I would venture to suggest that the **[Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA)](https://w3c.github.io/aria/)** standard is largely intended to add semantics to non-semantic HTML elements, including the HTML element `<div>`.

Summary: The use of semantic HTML elements makes it easier to understand the structure of the content, including users with disabilities.